# Remove prop from ...this.props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I am looking for is a quick way to remove a prop before passing `...this.props` to another React Component. Currently I have a Higher Order Component that performs some logic and then passes all its props to another component, but the next component doesn't need one of the props. Is it possible to remove that prop while still using `...this.props` or do I have to send each prop individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the rest operator with destructuring to achieve the desired result as follows:

```js
const props = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

// We want newProps without b

const { b, ...newProps } = props;

console.log(newProps);
```

Alternatively, you can copy the object and delete the undesired prop from the new object.

```js
const props = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

const newProps = { ...props };
delete newProps.b;

console.log(newProps);
```

At this point, you can spread your `newProps` into the returned component:

```
<MyComponent {...newProps} />
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use [rest destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) like so:

```js
/* Full set of input props, with "dontWant" that you would like to exclude */
const props = { dontWant : true, keep : 1, keepAlso : 2 }

/* Obtain filteredProps, which contains all of props without the dontWant prop */
const { dontWant, ...filteredProps } = props

console.log("Original props:", props)
console.log("Filtered props to use:", filteredProps)
```